# How do you number theorems but not definitions?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am using LaTeX theorem style where I have at the top:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
```

and then I use

```
\begin{(theorem|definition|lemma)}
...
\end{(theorem|definition|lemma)}
```

This numbers the theorems, definitions, and lemmas separately. Is where a way to do it where the definitions aren't numbered (but still use the rest of the theorem style)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get unnumbered theorem-like environment loading either **amsthm** or **ntheorem** and saying

```
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
```

These two packages introduce also the concept of "theorem style" that helps to get, for example, upright text inside the `definition` environment. For **amsthm** it would be

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition}
```

and similarly for **ntheorem**

Answer (score 7):

With the front-end package `thmtools` (and `amsthm` or `ntheorem` as back-ends), the corresponding definitions for the two structures would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no]{definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
  Test
\end{theorem}   

\begin{definition}
  Test
\end{definition}    

\end{document}
```

The `definition` pre-defined style from `amsthm` can be used by saying

```
\declaretheorem[style=definition,numbered=no]{definition}
```