# How do I add \begin{definition} … \end{definition}?

Tags: equations, formatting, numbering, listings, theorems

I have the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newcommand{\subscript}[2]{$#1 _ #2$}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\title{Jumbo}



\author{Frode Alfson Bj\o{}rdal}
\date{}




\begin{document}
```

How can I get `\begin{definition} … \end {definition}` here?

Comment: See how you defined `theorem`. Also you might want to have a look in the `amsthm` manual to familiarize yourself with the `\newtheorem` syntax.

Comment: Also note that your example has no chance to work as `\institute` and `\email` is not defined in the `article` class

Comment: In reality I have %\institute{Affiliation Institute \at Collegium Anonymia \\\email{clancularius@collegium.com}}, and so I delete this from my MWE.

Answer (score 33):

Just define it using `\newtheorem` like you have done for environment `theorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
  This is a definition.
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See also: [How do you number theorems but not definitions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19044).

For more information about `\newtheorem` and how to use another style for the new theorem environment `definition`, e.g., using `\theoremstyle{definition}` before `\newtheorem`, see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) of [package `amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm).

Comment: if upright text is wanted (more usual for a definition), precede the `\newtheorem{definition}` by `\theoremstyle{definition}`.  (defined by `amsthm`.)