# iosart2x.cls of IOS Press

Tags: pdftex

I use iosart2x.cls of IOS Press to write an article, I want to write a definition but don't see the \begin{definition} tag. Please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where can the class be downloaded from?

Comment: perhaps duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385675/how-do-i-add-begindefinition-enddefinition